# RxJS wait until desired value with timeout

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm using RxJS 6.6.0

Let's say I have a boolean observable with initial value `false`.

```
value$: Observable<boolean>;
```

I want to wait until this observable changes to `true` when a button is clicked, with a timeout of 2 seconds.

Here my code:

```
async onButtonClick(): Promise<void> {
    const isTrue = await this.value$.pipe(
          filter(e => e == true),
          // if it's not true after 2 seconds, return false!
        ).toPromise();

    if (isTrue) {
      console.log('Success')
    }
}
```

How to achieve this with RxJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `timeoutWith()` for that and you'll probably need `take(1)` as well to complete the chain so `toPromise()` knows when to resolve (in case value$ doesn't complete itself).

```
const isTrue = await this.value$.pipe(
  filter(e => e),
  timeoutWith(2000, of(false)),
  take(1),
).toPromise();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to avoid Promise do things in this way:

```
  this.value$.pipe(
    filter(Boolean),
    debounceTime(2000),
    take(1) // if you want to complete an Observable after first true emission
 ).subscribe(
     () => console.log('Success')
 );
```

[filter](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/filter)(Boolean) will prevent falsey value emissions and will only emit values that pass the provided condition, in your case true.

[debounceTime](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime) delays the values emitted by the source.

[take](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take)(1) Emits only the first count values emitted by the source Observable. Usualy it is a good thing that this be the last function called in the pipe chain